# Run a Relative Path in Windows?

Tags: vb.net, process

I'm attempting to run a destination relative path from within a VB.NET app. I've made sure to use backslashes (rather than forward slashes), and also running the Process with the working directory set to the correct source path; still getting a `The system cannot find the file specified` error when trying to run it.

**For example, I have (pseudo-code):**

`txtSource.text path = "C:\Windows\System32"`

`txtResult.text path = "..\notepad.exe"`

**Here's the Sub so far:**

```
Private Sub btnTest_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnTest.Click

    Try

        ' Create the process object
        Dim pRun As New Process()

        ' Set it to run from the Source folder (Working Directory)
        With pRun.StartInfo
            .UseShellExecute = False
            .WorkingDirectory = IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(txtSource.Text.Trim)
            .FileName = txtResult.Text.Trim
        End With

        pRun.Start()

        ' Wait for it to finish
        pRun.WaitForExit()

    Catch ex As Exception

        Debug.Print(ex.Message)

    End Try

End Sub
```

Comment: Two dots (`..`) means one directory level higher than current. One dot (`.`) means the current directory.

Comment: In this example C:\Windows\notepad.exe is one directory level higher than C:\Windows\System32.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`IO.Path.GetDirectoryName("C:\Windows\System32")` returns "C:\Windows"; the directory that contains "C:\Windows\System32".

`StartInfo.Filename =  "..\notepad.exe"` tells the process to look for `notepad.exe` in "C:\".

Also, for this to work, you need to set `StartInfo.UseShellExecute = True`; see: [ProcessStartInfo Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo(v=vs.110).aspx) for the description.

```
With pRun.StartInfo
    .UseShellExecute = True
    .WorkingDirectory = txtSource.Text.Trim
    .FileName = txtResult.Text.Trim
End With
```

Comment: Aha! For the example I originally had txtSource set to a full path including an actual file name, but shortened it for the example without double-checking first, lol, but setting `.UseShellExecute` to `True` was the key. It's always those little things you miss when you've spent 12 hours a day coding, for days, lol. Thanks!